# What's a good idiom or phrase that expresses that someone is corrupt and is working for a company or someone?

Tags: phrase-request, idiom-request

What's a good idiom or phrase that expresses that someone is corrupt and is working for a company or someone? There are political shows where it was used, but I don't remember exactly what the expression was, so I am wondering if someone knows what the phrase or idiom might be or know another idiom or phrase than the one I forgot about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the idiom **in somebody’s pocket**. TFD defines it like this:

> #### in (one's) pocket
>
> Under one's control or influence, especially in an underhanded or unethical way, such as by bribery or extortion.
>   *It's pretty obvious that our national legislators are all in corporate bigwigs' pockets!*
>   *I hear that the boss has half the police force in his pocket.*

Here is the expression used in a 2010 article from *The Atlantic*:

> Democrats have been accusing Republicans of being **in Big Oil's pocket** for years, ever since Vice President Dick Cheney's energy policy task force.

and here’s another example from *Time* (2014):

> D.C.'s teachers union spent $1 million to defeat the mayor who appointed her and elect a corrupt mayor who is **in the union's pocket**.

Answer (score 1):

Such a person can be said to have a *hidden agenda*:

> A secret or ulterior motive for something.
>
> - ‘They want to be certain that government officials don't have a hidden agenda.’
> - ‘But nothing concrete is happening, and the politicians are busy pursuing their own goals and hidden agendas rather than focussing on peace and security in the country.’

(source: [Oxford Dictionaries](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/hidden_agenda))